# Refresh Child panel with AjaxRequestTarget

Tags: wicket

I am new to wicket and stuck in a Panel refresh problem with AjaxRequestTarget. I am clarifying my scenario below.

In the Ui I have a Panel (A) which contains another Panel (B) and B contains some buttons and table. I Panel A, I have a Event which will refresh My Panel B with AjaxRequestTarget. On event I am adding Panel B in my AjaxRequestTarget.add() but it's not calling my initialize method in Panel B. So, Panel B is not refreshing properly.

It's a existing code so, can't move the event to Panel B. So, need to do something from Panel A itself.

Clarifying more:

After few debgus I found my problem in some other places. It's not about refreshing Panel B. It's all about refreshment of Panel A. 
Panel A extends **Panel** and when I am refreshing with Ajax Timer Panel A's components  scrumble up  and due to this My Panel B also scrumbled up. So, Can anyone help me on that

Comment: Can you provide us with some example that demonstrate your issue so it we can give you more clear answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put your "refreshing" code of the Panel B in the `onConfigure` method which is called once per request.

If you provide code sample my answer could be improved with an example.

Answer (score 0):

**onInitialize** is called when your component is added to the component hierarchy. **onConfigure** is called once per request processing for each component that is part of the request cycle (which yours is during Ajax if you add it to the Ajax request target). It is called for invisible components as well. Don't forget to call super().